# Segmentation Error for Large String in Parameter C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm finalizing a HW assignment to learn C++ coming from Java and had the code working until they tested it with the entire Gettysburg Address, now I get segment faults.  I cannot figure out how to solve this problem, I've tried creating a string using the NEW keyword but still can't get things to sizzle.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the function giving me problems.

```
void PalindromeFinder::truncateToLargestPalindrome(string& inputString){
 //std::string *big = new std::string;
 //*big=inputString;

int n = inputString.length();
int longestBegin = 0;
int maxLen = 1;
bool table[1000][1000] = {false};

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    table[i][i] = true;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
if (inputString[i] == inputString[i+1]) {
  table[i][i+1] = true;
  longestBegin = i;
  maxLen = 2;
}
}

for (int len = 3; len <= n; len++) {
for (int i = 0; i < n-len+1; i++) {
  int j = i+len-1;
  if (inputString[i] == inputString[j] && table[i+1][j-1]) {
    table[i][j] = true;
    longestBegin = i;
    maxLen = len;
  }
}
}

if(largestPalindromeFound.length()<inputString.substr(longestBegin, maxLen).length()){
this->largestPalindromeFound = inputString.substr(longestBegin, maxLen);}
}
```

Comment: Use a vector which you can allocate to the required size for the string.

Comment: You have a fixed size `table`, which for short input is mostly wasted, and for long input would result in overrunning the memory allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input string is bigger than 999 then you'll start accessing memory positions outside of your `table` matrix that's only 1000x1000.

Accessing memory positions outside of your allocated memory can yield segmentation faults and Gettysburg Address is longer than 1000 characters long.

Comment: Thank you for the input but it doesn't appear to be the size of the table that's bottle necking it.  I've increased the size to 10000 and it still errors.  Lincoln didn't talk that long.

Comment: @Mike The size of the table is definitely a problem. That just means it's not the only one.